# Closest location using pgr_withPoints for two points tables

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I would like to manually enter the (lat long) value into my sql code that then finds the shortest path via a line network to the closest points from an existing points table.  I have been looking at the pgr_withPointsCost function, but I am new to this and can't figure out from the syntax example on the website and pgRouting practical guide on how to actually implement this.  The guide utilizes a couple of functions to insert virtual nodes and the syntax is uncommented so I don't know what they are doing.  I looked around here and found a potential solution, but I am new to SQL programming and can't connect some of the elements together.

I have created the routable network graph as one would normally do with pgr_dijkstra (source, target, cost, reverse_cost), but after that there are a couple of steps and parts of the code that I am unsure about:

Step 1: Insert location of start point into the points table of points that I would like to route to.

```
-- Add location to points table
INSERT INTO cntl_pts.cp(cp_no, geom)
VALUES ('rel1', ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(-117.742995, 54.435532),4326) );
CREATE INDEX idx_cp ON cntl_pts.cp USING gist(geom);
```

I am unsure how use two point tables in the pgr_withPointsCost operation, so I enter it into the existing points table then place that point into a temporary table to perform a proximity operation to reduce the number of points to just the nearby points.

```
-- Place newly entered point into temporary table
CREATE TEMP TABLE from_pt AS
SELECT * FROM cntl_pts.cp WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM cntl_pts.cp);

 CREATE TEMP TABLE cp_locations AS
SELECT r.cp_no AS cp_loc, c.id, c.pid, c.edge_id, c.fraction, c.closest_node, c.cp_no, c.geom,
(ST_Distance(r.geom::geography, c.geom::geography)/1000)::integer As dist_km -- convert to km
FROM from_pt As r LEFT JOIN cntl_pts.cp As c
ON ST_DWithin(r.geom::geography, c.geom::geography,20000) --  distance in meters
ORDER BY dist_km;

-- Cost path from_pt to nearest cp_locations
SELECT *
FROM   pgr_withPointsCost(
         'SELECT id, source, target, length as cost, reverse_cost FROM 
          public.streams,
         'SELECT cp_locations.id AS pid,
                 public.streams.id,
                 public.streams.fraction
          FROM   cp_locations AS pnt
          CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT id AS edge_id,
                   ST_LineLocatePoint(public.streams.geom, pnt.geom) AS fraction
            FROM   public.streams
            ORDER BY
                   public.streams.geom <-> pnt.geom
          ) AS edg',
        details := TRUE
      );
```

Comment: Have you read through the docs? The withPoints functions are pretty well documented https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/withPoints-family.html - if you can share some of your data via a github gist, I can have a closer look

Comment: Thanks @TimothyDalton.  I have the pgRouting A Practical Guide and have decided that I will give the code recipe they give.  It is just that there are a couple of functions and some parts I don't get.  I will edit my question with the new kick-at-the-can.

Comment: @TimothyDalton I have a repository setup in https://github.com/matthewmeadows81.

Comment: sorry for my late response, do you still need support here? I downloaded the data and can have a look

Comment: @TimothyDalton, anything you can do to steer me in the right direction will be much appreciated.